# Inject a @RequestScoped bean twice as different instances

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have the following situation (Java EE, CDI, jax.rs):

I have a RequestScoped Bean, which stores some data used in the live time of a request:

```
MyHandler.java:
@RequestScoped
public class MyHandler
{
    ....
}
```

Then I have my REST call, which uses two **different** instances of my Handler Bean:

```
MyRestCall.java:
@Stateless
public class MyRestCall
{
    @Inject
    MyHandler handlerA;

    @Inject
    MyHandler handlerB;

    ....
}
```

However, what happens is, that *hanlderA* and *handlerB* is the same object. But I would like to have two different ones. How can I achieve that in a proper way? Of course, I could create a base class *Handler* and then derive two separate classes *HandlerA* and *HandlerB* and @Inject them as *handlerA* and *handlerB*. But I hope for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bean is request scope so there should be exactly and only one such a bean served through all processing during request lifecycle. You should not expect to get a new one.

The scope that have such a behaviour is a `@Dependent` scope. Have you thought about using it for that bean? It will produce new bean every time you do inject of it so it look like a better solution for that. Of course in other places that you are using the same bean there will be the new one injected.

Comment: Short and precise! Thank you very much! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`Instance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) annotate with [`@New`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/New.html):

```
@Inject
@New(MyHandler.class)
Instance<MyHandler> handlerInstanceA;

@Inject
@New(MyHandler.class)
Instance<MyHandler> handlerInstanceB;
```

And then get your instances using:

```
MyHandler handlerA = handlerInstanceA.get();
MyHandler handlerB = handlerInstanceB.get();
```

### Update

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/New.html) says that [`@New`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/New.html) was deprecated in CDI 1.1 and the [`@Dependent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html) scope should be used instead:

> The [`New`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/New.html) qualifier was deprecated in CDI 1.1. CDI applications are encouraged to inject [`Dependent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html) scoped beans instead.

So use:

```
@Inject
MyHandler handlerA;

@Inject
MyHandler handlerB;
```

Since `@Dependent` is the default CDI scope, leave your `MyHandler` without annotations or annotate it with `@Dependent`:

```
@Dependent
public class MyHandler {...}
```

According to the `@Dependent` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html):

> Beans declared with scope [`@Dependent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html) behave differently to beans with other built-in scope types. When a bean is declared to have scope [`@Dependent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html):
>
> • No injected instance of the bean is ever shared between multiple injection points.
> • Any instance of the bean injected into an object that is being created by the container is bound to the lifecycle of the newly created object.